# Python and C++ nodes in the same package

Tags: ros, python, c++, package, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package containing some C++ nodes. How do I add a Python node using rosbuild?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163821/python-and-c++-nodes-in-the-same-package/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-11

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just create your python node, then make the script executable and all should be fine. But also consider why you would want to do this in the first place.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-12**:
Why not, having for example Python node for robot's hearing and automatic speech recognition and C++ node for vision and image processing, both in robot interaction package.

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2014-05-21**:
I'm also curious as to why you advise to consider doing this. Oftentimes a simple interpreted script that can be edited on the fly works much better than a compiled application, at least in the research environment.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-21**:
So if you had already implemented C++ code from older lectures/projects, you would bother translate it to Python first for the sake of on the fly editing?

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2014-05-22**:
No, unless it was completely unmaintainable, I would not bother translating any existing code because it would be a duplication of effort. I don't think we're talking about duplicating existing C++ nodes in Python, but rather having them live side-by-side.